# why the number of the support vector is zero?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I use the libsvm tool to do the classification. but the number of the support vector turns out to be zero, which  means there is no support vector. Why? what does it mean and what are the main reasons?

Answer (score 1):

It means, that parameters and data used for training led to the trivial model (always equal to one of the classes). So what are the most probable reasons?

- Bad choice of SVM parameters (`C`, `gamma`, `degree`, depending on used kernel)
- Wrong data (inconsistent, check what exactly are you feeding as `X` and `Y` matrices)